# efficient way of making a graph of a dictionary

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, graph, distance

What is the most efficient way of making a graph of the words in a dictionary with hamming distance=1??

Comment: Do you want "a" graph for the whole dictionary, or a graph starting from certain word?

Comment: what would be the approach for each??

Comment: That's two questions! :)

Comment: A graph starting from 1 word.

Comment: @belisarius Er? He wants a graph of words with hamming distance 1. It doesn't matter where you start - the resultant graph will be the same.

Comment: @Nick I tried to imply "one connected graph" starting from some point vs. "all the connected sub-graphs for your dictionary". Perhaps I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hamming distance is only defined for words of equal length, so you'll actually have one disjoint graph for each word length in your dictionary. If you meant [levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance, which permits insertions and deletions, then you will indeed have a single graph.

One option is to construct a [BK-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bk-tree) from your dictionary. While not strictly speaking a graph, it allows you to ask the same questions (getting a list of elements with a given distance), and takes O(n log n) time to construct.

Another option is brute-force: For every word, test its distance to all candidate words. You can narrow down candidate words to those of the same length (or length one less or greater, for levenshtein). This is O(n^2) worst-case, but this may be acceptable if you're not building the graph more than once.

Theoretically, there's probably an O(n log n) method of constructing the graph - in the trivial case, constructing a BK-tree, then generating the graph from that is O(mn log n), where m is the average number of edges per node - but I'm not aware of an elegant one.

Comment: The brute force approach is actually `O(n^2 * l)` where `l` is the maximum length of a word in the dictionary. Since there are `n` words in the dictionary `l` is at least `log n / log 26`, and so the brute force approach is, at best, `O(n^2 log n)`.

Comment: Let's assume that hash set lookups and insertions are constant, and that the alphabet has 26 characters. Build a hash set of everything in the dictionary - `O(n * l)`. For every word in the dictionary, lookup in the hash set that word's `l * 25` possible hamming neighbors (`l * 50` or so levenshtein neighbors) - `O(n * l * l)`. If `l ~ log(n)` then overall this is `O(n (log n)^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an adjacency map `map<string, list<string>` to represent the graph. It maps a graph node (a word in our case) to the list of the adjacent nodes (i.e. all words within distance == 1).

How to populate this map ? First, break down the dictionary into sets of words of the same length `set<string> wordset[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]` and populate the map as follows.

```
map<string, list<string>> adjacency_map
for each wordset in wordset array  
  for each w1 in wordset
     for each w2 in wordset
        if one_char_off(w1, w2) { // if the distance between w1 and w2 == 1
           update(adjacency_map, w1, w2)
           update(adjacency_map, w2, w1)
        }
```

Function `one_char_off(string w1, string w2)` checks if the distance between w1 and w2 is 1.

```
int diff = 0
for i in [0, w1.length) // both w1 and w2 have the same length
   if w1[i] != w2[i]
      if ++diff > 1
         return false
return diff == 1
```

Function `update(map<string, list<string>> adjacency_map, string w1, string w2)` adds the pair of adjacent words `w1` and `w2` to the adjacent map.